# Issue with image lining up with text in email signature

Tags: html

Unable to place image even with the signature in table. The top pf the image should be the same level as the top of the text

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Email Signature</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;
        max-width: 560px">
    <tr>
      <td width="5%" valign="middle">
        <img href="https://www.pravoconstruction.com/" src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C4E0BAQGQicp-n_FWzw/company-logo_200_200/0/1530564205372?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=OdxbaYftUNG_-cf8lLTWVA-voPANK8goWs3hiafOo84" style="width: 30%;min-width: 62px;
                  display: block;">
      </td>
      <td width="70%" valign="top">
        <h4 style="margin:0 0 5px; font-size: 9px;font-family: arial;color:#99A3A4; line-height:1.2"><strong>test email</strong></h4>
        <h5 style="margin:0 0 5px; font-size: 8px;font-family: arial;color:#99A3A4; line-height:1.2">job role | 123.456.7890</h5>
        <h5 style="margin:0 0 5px; font-size: 8px;font-family: arial;color:#99A3A4; line-height:1.2">1234 anywhere lane | Texas,TX 77777</h5>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your photo has some space *inside the image* which probably causes it to look not lined up. If you want to compensate for that I would suggest adding some padding to the top of the h4.

Also, you could crop the image so it doesn't have this space on the top.

[image: Image showing whitespace]

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue. It also doesn't help that google doesn't really allow you to do as much when copy and pasting to the signature box.